# Pixel Shader, YUV-RGB Conversion failing

Tags: hlsl, fragment-shader, sharpdx

I am tasked with playing back a video hthat comes in in a YUV format as an overlay in a larger game. I am not a specialist in Direct3d, so I am struggling. I managed to get a shader working and am rendering 3 textures (Y, V, U). Sadly I am totally unable to get anything like a decent image. Documentation is also failing me. I am currently loading the different data planes (Y,V,U) in three different textures:

```
m_Textures = new Texture[3];
// Y Plane
m_Textures[0] = new Texture(m_Device, w, h, 1, Usage.None, Format.L8, Pool.Managed);
// V Plane
m_Textures[1] = new Texture(m_Device, w2, h2, 1, Usage.None, Format.L8, Pool.Managed);
// U Plane
m_Textures[2] = new Texture(m_Device, w2, h2, 1, Usage.None, Format.L8, Pool.Managed);
```

When I am rendering them as R, G and B respectively with the following code:

```
float4 Pixel(float2 texCoord: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float y = tex2D (ytexture, texCoord);
    float v = tex2D (vtexture, texCoord);
    float u = tex2D (utexture, texCoord);

    //R = Y + 1.140 (V -128)
    //G = Y - 0.395 (U-128) - 0.581 (V-128)
    //B = Y + 2.028 (U-128)     

    float r = y; //y + 1.140 * v;
    float g = v; //y - 0.395 * u - 0.581 * v;
    float b = u; //y + 2.028 * u;

    float4 result;
    result.a = 255;
    result.r = r; //clamp (r, 0, 255);
    result.g = g; //clamp (g, 0, 255);
    result.b = b; //clamp (b, 0, 255);

    return result;
}
```

Then the resulting image is - quite funny. I can see the image, but colors are totally distorted, as it should be.

The formula I should apply shows up in the comment of the pixel shader, but when I do it, the resulting image is pretty brutally magenta only. This gets me to the question - when I read out an L8 texture into a float, with

```
float y = tex2D (ytexture, texCoord);
```

what is the range of values? The "origin" values are 1 byte, 0 to 255, and the forum I have assumes this. Naturally I am totally off when the values returned are somehow normalized. My Clamp operation at the end also will fail if for example colors in a pixel shader are normalized 0 to 1. Anyone an idea how that works? Please point me also to documentation - I have not found anything in this regard.

Comment: Don't know HLSL, but I'd expect the values read from the texture to be between 0 and 1, not 0 and 255.  Try y *= 256 and see what it gets you?  Second point, why not just convert to RGB when decoding the video, rather than doing it in a shader?  Or put the YUV values into the 'RGB' labelled channels of a single texture and do the conversion in the shader, but avoid three separate layers on the GPU side?

Comment: Did and that actually worked ;) The conversion is out of my hand in this case - the format is fixed and the image is life and the decoder can not do additional transpositions. The layers also have different sized (U and V are quarter images, half width and height). Please add as answer and I will approve ;)

Comment: Eh which bit of my advice worked?  The *256 bit, right?  Yeah, I've played with some pretty split up YUV plane decoding myself in the past and usually your hands are pretty tied.  (What SO needs is a way to mark a *comment* as the accepted Answer)

Comment: Yeah. Multiplied with 256. Still looking for a better way to debug Shaders in Visual Studio ;) I would have seen this immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tex2D(sampler,pos)` return values between 0 and 1.

Multiply by 255.0 to get your expected range.